# Arrange multiple UIViews with in table cell view based on user action either move to left or right (using Xamarin IOS and XIB)

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I'm new to IOS based development. I have a following requirement to implement table view.[That's how the view should arrange based on user action(move to left or right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF5D4.jpg)

My plan is arranged all the images in Image View and based on the user tap to left/right need to rearrange/hide/show the images. I'm not able to achieve this dynamically. All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code , just place the corresponding images into `Resource` folder.

```
public class MyCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        private float buttonWidth = 50;
        private float buttonHeight = 100;
        private float largeButtonWidth = 0;
        private List<string> imageList;
        private List<string> largeImageList;
        private List<UIButton> buttonList;

        public MyCell()
        {
            largeButtonWidth = (float)(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - buttonWidth * 2);
            imageList = new List<string> { "1.png", "2.png" , "3.png"};
            largeImageList = new List<string> { "bg1.PNG", "bg2.PNG", "bg3.PNG" };
            buttonList = new List<UIButton>();

            for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
            {
                UIButton button = new UIButton();
                button.Tag = i;
                button.Frame = new CGRect(buttonWidth * i, 0, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
                button.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle(imageList[i]), UIControlState.Normal);
                button.TouchUpInside += Button_TouchUpInside;
                this.ContentView.Add(button);
                buttonList.Add(button);
            }
        }

        private void Button_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reset();

            UIButton button = sender as UIButton;
            button.SetImage(null, UIControlState.Normal);
            button.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle(largeImageList[(int)button.Tag]), UIControlState.Normal);

            CGRect frame = button.Frame;
            frame.Width = largeButtonWidth;
            button.Frame = frame;

            UIButton button2 = buttonList[1];
            CGRect frame2 = button2.Frame;
            frame2.X = buttonList[0].Frame.Right;
            button2.Frame = frame2;

            UIButton button3 = buttonList[2];
            CGRect frame3 = button3.Frame;
            frame3.X = buttonList[1].Frame.Right;
            button3.Frame = frame3;
        }

        void reset()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
            {
                UIButton button = buttonList[i];

                button.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle(imageList[i]), UIControlState.Normal);
                button.SetBackgroundImage(null, UIControlState.Normal);

                CGRect frame = button.Frame;
                frame.Width = buttonWidth;
                button.Frame = frame;
            }
        }      
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let me try. Thank you very much. Your help is much appreciated

Comment: I have used your idea to make it work with UIVIEW. Thanks